# Turning a random number to a palindrome with Java

Tags: java, palindrome

I'm trying to make a random number to be a palindrome. For example, generated random number 1234 should become 12344321.

So I wrote this code:

```
int num = (int)((Math.random()*100000)+1);
int palindrome = num;

System.out.println(num);

while (num > 0)
{

    palindrome = palindrome*10+num%10;
    num = num/10;
}

System.out.println("Palindrome: " + palindrome);
```

Sometimes it works, and I get, for example, number 6540 and palindrome 65400456. But for some reason in most cases I get, for example, number 94229 and palindrome 833057657. Or number 82270 and palindrome -362927364.

Why is it happening? What's wrong with this code and how to fix it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to integer overflow. An `int` is 32 bits wide and is therefore limited to values between `-2,147,483,648` and `2,147,483,647`.

Taking `94229` as an example, `9422992249` modulo `(1<<32)` is `833057657`, which is what you're getting.

Change `int`s to `long`s, and that'll increase the range of numbers your code will be able to handle (the range will, of course, remain limited).

If you need to go even further, [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) (or strings) may be the answer.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. Thank you very much! PS. I can't accept an answer for the next 8 minutes or sow (don't know why), but will do it once I can.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting overflow, the numbers are greater than 2^31-1, which is the limit on integers.  Try using a long instead.

Comment: The limit is 2^31 - 1 due to signedness.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it won't work. Since the int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647 (inclusive). For integral values, this data type is generally the default choice unless there is a reason (like the above) to choose something else. This data type will most likely be large enough for the numbers your program will use, but if you need a wider range of values, use long instead.

### Range Limit:

```
int -->    -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 
long -->   -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807
```